# /i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find an existing library

Tags: c++, qt, linker, subdirectory, qmake

I am facing the following issue when trying to build my c++/Qt project:

[image]

I am using qmake. The Following instruction was added in the .pro

LIBS += -LC:\Users\ik\Documents\Projets\cap3600project\cap3600\ExternLibraries\lib -lqwt

I have the following error "i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lqwt"

The library qwt.dll is present in "C:\Users\ik\Documents\Projets\cap3600project\cap3600\ExternLibraries\lib" directory.

[image]

I have no idea about the root cause of this issue.

Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea about the root cause of this issue.

The root cause is that the `-lqwt` argument asks the linker to locate a file called `libqwt.lib`, which in fact is nowhere to be found.

I am not sure whether MingW `ld.exe` can link directly against `.DLL`. If it can, using `-l:qwt.dll` will let the library be found.